# Eurocard backplane dimensions

Tags: pcb, mount

Does anybody have a detailed drawing of a 3U backplane for mounting eurocards in a 19" rack. My eurocards use the Harting din 41612 connectors. I'll looking for information on the position of the backplane connectors to make sure the eurocards line up with the guide rails etc.

Comment: Search for IEC 61076-4-113; does [this, p. 7](https://elektronik.heitec.de/04-elektronik/03-gehaeusetechnik/Technology-Expertise.pdf) help?

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed.